# ProgId for ThunderRT6UserControlDC

Tags: activex

I have a ActiveX control with classname as ThunderRT6UserControlDC in our application, can you please let me know what could be it's ProgId and it's OCX filename.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the Windows SDK installed and open this application (path may be slightly different):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\oleview.exe
```

Start this application with administrative privileges to have the best experience in using it.

In the treeview to the left, go to TypeLibraries and search for your ThunderRT6-Library. On the right side, you can find your information about the TypeId (the guid) and the exact filenames for 32/64bit.

Comment: Under TypeLibraries ThunderRT6-Library library is not available.

Comment: I guess you checked similar names. I don't know these component library but I guessed the name starts with ThunderRT6. You know the manufacturers name? With what name is the control listed in the add reference dialog?

Comment: I don't kow the manufacturer's name. Inspect tool is showing it as a Pane control with classname ThunderRT6UserControlDC, this is the only information i have about the control.

Comment: It seems like this is a common classname used in legacy VB 6 for user controls. Most of these controls would be located in Microsoft Windows Common Controls (MSCOMCT2.OCX or COMCTL32.OCX). Maybe I should ask you: What are you trying to achieve (bigger picture)?

Comment: This control is located in CmboPls1.ocx . I am trying to get its ProgID and register it in ROT, so that i can use it for automation. FYI - I already have a exe which accepts controls handle(HWND) as argument and registers it in ROT.

Comment: Too bad I don't have this *.ocx on my machine, but there should be an entry in the TypeLibrary view as described in my answer. If you have time, you can go through the list and check on the right side if CmboPls1.ocx appears there. If yes -> double click the assembly and get the information you need.